# What's the difference between "\x85" and "\u{85}" in Crystal?

Tags: crystal-lang, unicode-escapes

I know `\u{...}` can be used to specify a unicode codepoint in hexadecimal.

However, `"\x86"` != `"\u{86}"`.  But, `"\x7F"` == `"\u{7F}"`.

What's the difference between the `\x` and `\u` escape sequences?

Answer (score 2):

The `"\xNN"` seems to handle ASCII codes in hexadecimal format. The `"\uNNNN"` and `"\u{NN}"` handle Unicode codepoints in hexadecimal format.

ASCII only goes up to 127 in decimal format (HEX: 7F), So that would explain why the codepoint 126 (HEX: 7E, "~" character) works, but 128 (HEX: 80) and above (HEX: 85, 86, etc) does not work using the `\xNN` escape sequence.

You can see what's going on "underneath" by using the String#codepoints method.

```
puts "\x7F".inspect    # "~"
puts "\x7F".codepoints # [126]
# =====================================
puts "\x80".inspect    # "\x80" (Invalid ASCII codepoint.)
puts "\x80".codepoints # [65533]
# =====================================
puts "\u{80}".inspect    # "\u0080" (Valid Unicode codepoint.)
puts "\u{80}".codepoints # [128]
```

Crystal replaces the invalid codepoints with 65533, the replacement character which basically says, "This is invalid for this encoding".